# This program should ask user for the max num to print out to and then calculate each number starting from 1 to the maximum along with it squared

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter the max number:");

    int max = input.nextInt();

    int[]arr1 = new int[max+1];
    int[]arr2 = new int[max+1];
    int[]arr3 = new int[max+1];

    int i = 1;

    // For-loop to calculate 
    for (i = 1;i <= max;i++)
        arr1[i] = arr1[i-1] + i;

    i = 1;

    // While-loop to calculate
    while (i <= max) {
        arr2[i] = arr2[i-1] + i;
        i++;
    }

    i = 1;

    // Do-While-loop to calculate
    do
        arr3[i] = arr3[i-1] + i;
    while (++i <= max);

    for (i = 0; i <= max; i++)
        System.out.println("Arr1 " + arr1[i] + " Arr2 " + arr2[i] + " Arr3 " + arr3[i]);

    System.out.println("Sum of All is " + arr1[max]);

}
```

I have this for doing sums but I am stuck when it comes to getting it to square

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Assignments aren't usually arbitrary; your instructor, tutorial, or course will have covered the necessary topics to make it possible for you to do this. **Review your course materials, class notes, etc.,** and try to do the work. *If* you run into a *specific* problem, research it thoroughly, [search thoroughly here](/help/searching), and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Please provide the shortest example that still shows your problem.

Comment: Can you provide your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have 3 identical `array` objects?

Anyway, it's pretty straightforward to print the square of all numbers from 1 to `max`:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
    System.out.println(i + ": " + i * i);
}
```

There are also some fun ways to sum up the numbers from 1 to `max`, such as:

```
System.out.println(IntStream.range(1, max + 1).sum());
```